# `tex4ebook` error

Tags: errors, tex4ebook, command-line

When I run tex4ebook on a project, I get the following error:

```
tex4ebook -f epub3 generated-latex.tex
[STATUS]  tex4ebook: Conversion started
[STATUS]  tex4ebook: Input file: generated-latex.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
Der Befehl "tidy" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
[WARNING] exec_epub: tidy command seems missing, you should install it in order
  to make valid epub file

zip error: Internal logic error (fstat(stdin))
...023/texmf-dist/scripts/tex4ebook/tex4ebook-exec_epub.lua:295: exit
C:\texlive\2023\bin\windows\runscript.tlu:921: command failed with exit code 1:
texlua c:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\scripts\tex4ebook\tex4ebook -f epub3 generated-latex.tex
```

Example document:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Test}

Test

\end{document}
```

Google didn't give good results, so I thought I'd start a question to help others running into the issue in the future.

Some help or hint is also appreciated!

Issue on GitHub: https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ebook/issues/115

Comment: I also wanted to add sample code to the question, but editing it fails, currently.

Comment: you can get tidy here https://www.html-tidy.org, simply add it to your path.

Comment: After some research, it seems like there is a problem packing the EPUB file with the `zip` command, here is the line apparently causing the error in the code: https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ebook/blob/master/tex4ebook-exec_epub.lua#L295

Comment: `tidy` doesn't seem to be the problem, here. That seems to be just a warning, but the actual error happens later, as written in my comment above.

Comment: in a short example I had no problems (I'm on window too).

Comment: Hm. Do you use texlive 2023?

Comment: yes, updated today.

Comment: Maybe I'll try updating tex4ebook again explicitly. My version is from a few months ago, I think. I am on Windows 11, BTW.

Comment: But maybe that won't do good. If I read correctly, the versions for the distribution are frozen once a year, so you should probably have the same as I have.

Comment: I added an example document now (not sure if even relevant) and also linked the issue on the `tex4ebook` GitHub page that I just created.